# Sorting table with multiple tbody by first row only of every tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-multisortable

I'm trying to sort a table with multiple tbodies using jquery plugin tablesorter.
The problem maybe is that I have a table inside the tbodies in the second row, and I think it is confusing the plugin. I've found [This](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-sort-tbodies.html) which is very similar to my case, but mine is a little different.
Now the table has the first row with the data I have to sort, and the second row is hidden (unless you click it), in the second row I have a td with another table, but this data I don't need to sort. The table is built with js. Please let me know what I can do.
The table looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-dark table-hover vertical-align tablesorter" id="tableID">                
    <thead id="thead_table">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Nome</th>
            <th scope="col">Attività</th>
            <th scope="col">Referente</th>
            <th scope="col">Categoria</th>
            <th scope="col">Priorità</th>                                
            <th scope="col">Gruppi</th>
            <th scope="col">Scadenza</th>                                
            <th scope="col">Azioni</th>
            <th scope="col">Stato</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody_52">                
        <tr onclick="clicked_Attivita(this)" id="tr_52" value="52" class="table-dark tr_a" name="n_52">
            <th scope="row">52</th>
            <td>Pippo</td>
            <td>awerf</td>
            <td>Paperino</td>
            <td>/</td>
            <td>Bassa</td>
            <td><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Ingegneria">ING</span> </td>
            <td>26-01-2023</td>            
            <td><i class="fas fa-duotone fa-circle-check" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Completato" onclick="closeAttivita(this, event)"></i></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="100%" class="align-middle td_sa table-active" id="52" onclick="clicked_td_sa(this)" style="padding-top: 12px;padding-bottom: 12px;">
                <table id="t_Sa_52" class="table table-sm table-dark table_sa" style="width:100%; display: none; margin:0px;" name="table_sa">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col style="width: 20%;">
                        <col style="width: 50%;">
                        <col style="width: 15%;">
                        <col style="width: 15%;"> 
                    </colgroup>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr width="100%">
                            <td>Altri utenti: </td>
                            <td colspan="3">Pippo, Paperino, Minnie</td>                                             
                        </tr>                       
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="tbody_67">                
        <tr onclick="clicked_Attivita(this)" id="tr_67" value="67" class="table-dark tr_a" name="n_67">
            <th scope="row">67</th>
            <td>Pippo</td>
            <td>bcbcbc</td>
            <td>Paperino</td>
            <td>Ingegneria</td>
            <td>Altissima</td>
            <td><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Ingegneria">ING</span> </td>
            <td>04-02-2023</td>            
            <td><i class="fas fa-duotone fa-circle-check" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Completato" onclick="closeAttivita(this, event)"></i> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="100%" class="align-middle td_sa table-active" id="67" onclick="clicked_td_sa(this)" style="padding-top: 12px;padding-bottom: 12px;">
                <table id="t_Sa_67" class="table table-sm table-dark table_sa" style="width:100%; display: none; margin:0px;" name="table_sa">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col style="width: 20%;">
                        <col style="width: 50%;">
                        <col style="width: 15%;">
                        <col style="width: 15%;"> 
                    </colgroup>
                
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="89" class="tr_sa_" name="n_67">
                            <td>Pluto</td>
                            <td>cdcd</td>
                            <td>02-02-2023</td>
                            <td><i class="fas fa-duotone fa-circle-check" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Completato" style="padding:5px;" onclick="close_sa(this, event)"></i></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr id="90" class="tr_sa_" name="n_67">
                            <td>Luca</td>
                            <td>av</td>
                            <td>27-01-2023</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr width="100%">
                            <td>Altri utenti: </td>
                            <td colspan="3">Pippo, Pippo, Pippo</td>                                             
                        </tr>                       
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="tbody_70">                
        <tr onclick="clicked_Attivita(this)" id="tr_70" value="70" class="table-dark tr_a" name="n_70">
            <th scope="row">70</th>
            <td>Pippo</td>
            <td>Riparare il riparabile</td>
            <td>Pippo</td>
            <td>Ingegneria</td>
            <td>Media</td>
            <td><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Ingegneria">ING</span> </td>
            <td>31-01-2023</td>            
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="100%" class="align-middle td_sa table-active" id="70" onclick="clicked_td_sa(this)" style="padding-top: 12px;padding-bottom: 12px;">
                <table id="t_Sa_70" class="table table-sm table-dark table_sa" style="width:100%; display: none; margin:0px;" name="table_sa">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col style="width: 20%;">
                        <col style="width: 50%;">
                        <col style="width: 15%;">
                        <col style="width: 15%;"> 
                    </colgroup>
                    
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="88" width="100%" class="tr_sa_">
                            <td style="background-color:#22732e;">Pippo</td>
                            <td>Sostituire anche il sostituibile</td>
                            <td>29-01-2023</td>
                            <td>25-01-2023</td>                               
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    
</table>
```

And jquery function:

```
function sortTable_(){
    $('#tableID').tablesorter({
        widgets: [ 'sortTbody' ],
        widgetOptions: {
          sortTbody_primaryRow : '.tr_a',
          sortTbody_sortRows   : false,
          sortTbody_noSort     : 'tablesorter-no-sort-tbody',
        }
      });
}
```

Thank you so much for the help and sorry if it's not a clear question please tell me
Have a good day :)

I'm trying to sort the table using multisort jquery plugin, but using just the first row for data

Comment: The table has 3 bodies? Do you have a picture of a sample of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The principal table has different items, which are grouped with tbody
Almost every item has the second row with another table, first it is hidden, if you click it shows like the last item in the picture. [Picture](https://imgur.com/dJVPkcF) . I just need to sort with the first row